# c# sqlDataAdapter to dataset multiple tables

Tags: c#, sql

I am running 4 queries that return calculated values into a dataset. It creates 4 tables (table, table1,table2 and table3) the default names are fine. I can loop through the tables and return all rows from all tables, but I need to set the 0 row in each table to a variable that I can use logic against. Like: dep1 = (table)row[i], dep2 = (table1)row[i], 
dep3 = (table2)row[i], dep4 =(table3)row[i] int i =0 then loop through the rows and return the values for dep1 to dep4. I can't find any reference to the syntax of looking at specifically each row of different tables in a dataset. How can I do that? I also want to count the rows returned in just 1 table, say table3, how do I do that?

Comment: Your [Enter] key seems to be broken.

Answer (score 1):

to set a value in Column 2 of row 0 of table 1 of the dataset:

```
ds.Tables[1].Rows[0][2] = 11.12;
```

to get the number of rows in Table 3 of the dataset:

```
var numRecords = ds.Tables[3].Rows.Count;
```

all arrays are zero-based.